# Error fetching access token when sending a firebase cloud message from a cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am trying to send a message to an iOS device using cloud functions with the code below, but it generates the following error when I deploy it in the terminal using

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

> Error sending message: FirebaseAppError: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND".

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as serviceAccount from "../../credentials/my-app-credentials.json";

admin.initializeApp({
  // credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount as admin.ServiceAccount),
});


const message: admin.messaging.Message = {
  notification: {
    title: "Test notification",
    body: "Sent from firebase cloud functions",
  },
  token: "<REDACTED>", 
};

admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error sending message:", error);
  });
```

Other notes:

- I am on the blaze plan
- When using the Compose notification page in firebase with a test message it works and it get's delivered to the iOS device.
- I have set up a service account with a key
- Other functions that access my firebase database work
- I tried a few variations to do admin.initializeApp, but none of them worked
- I am new to working with cloud functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the `my-app-credentials.json` is in the same directory as your Cloud Functions source file(s), or under that directory. If it isn't, it won't be deployed and thus won't be present when the function is run on Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Hi Frank, shouldn't the OP initialise the Admin SDK without passing any parameter/configuration (`admin.initializeApp()`) since it is within a CF? https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk

Comment: Fair point  Both can actually be valid, but without any config file is definitely easier when the use-case allows that (which is the most common). Want to post a separate answer for that?

Comment: Answer done ;-)

Comment: Thank you, the only way I got it to work was by moving the json into the same directory as the Cloud Functions source file. The more simple way using only ```admin.initializeApp()``` didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Cloud Function code you don't need to pass any argument to the `admin.initializeApp()` method.

By doing `admin.initializeApp()` you actually initialize the Admin SDK with Google Application Default Credentials, as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk).

This approach is also explained in the ["Get started"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=1st#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app_1) page of the Cloud Functions documentation.

Comment: Thank you, that was my initial approach, but I never got it to work and I get the same error as described in my initial post. Do you know what could be the reason?

I tried it like this:

```import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();
```

Comment: I guess you are using TypeScript, aren't you?

Comment: Yes I am using TypeScript

Comment: So `import * as admin from "firebase-admin";  admin.initializeApp();` is the correct way, look at this official Firebase video: https://youtu.be/7IkUgCLr5oA?t=200